# How can I pixelate an image via the command line on Linux

Tags: software-recommendation, pixelation

Is there a command-line utility for Linux that can pixelate an image by a specified percentage eg "-pixelate 30%"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the usual trick is to scale down so that you lose resolution and then scale up to magnify the low-res image. So with [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org), something like this:

```
convert -scale 10% -scale 1000% original.jpg pixelated.jpg
```

**UPDATE**: if you just want to be able to specify a single "pixelation amount" value, then the above command can be wrapped in a shell script as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
MAGICK=/usr/local/bin/convert

AMOUNT=$(echo "1.001 - $1" | bc -l)
INFILE=$2
OUFILE=$3

COEFF1=$(echo "100 * $AMOUNT" | bc -l)
COEFF2=$(echo "100 / $AMOUNT" | bc -l)

$MAGICK -scale $COEFF1% -scale $COEFF2% $INFILE $OUFILE
```

If you then save the above script as `pixelate.sh` and make it executable with `chmod 755 pixelate.sh`, you can run it by specifying a pixelation amount between *0-1*, an *input file* and an *output file*. For example:

```
./pixelate.sh 0.5 original.jpg pixelated.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks! For my purposes this works great. I've noticed that if you use an input image with a dimension ending in an odd number the output size is different from the input. However, I can live with this ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have ruby installed this might be a possible option for you.

See this gist https://gist.github.com/71598aeb1d823c9229ac

It uses chunky_png to pixellate the image, so you may need to adapt the code slightly if you want to produce other file formats.

For more information about it see this link
http://codebrawl.com/contests/pixelizing-images-with-chunkypng

Not sure how comfortable you with adapting code, but I could try to convert it into a simple command line application if you think it would be worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I like that it allows me to specify pixelation amount. I've marked Jamie's answer as the best answer as imagemagick is easier to install than chunkypng, but should I ever need a ruby solution I'll know where to look. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So, if you know how to do this with the Gimp via the point-and-click interface then you can probably write  batch-mode script to do the same thing on the command line:

http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't really provide me with an answer